# Using ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile makes the base image's CMD be ignored

Tags: docker, dockerfile

It looks as if when my Dockerfile uses an `ENTRYPOINT` script, its base image's `CMD` is ignored. Could anybody tell me why and/or where in the doc this behavior is explained?

Here is an example with a Dockerfile extending the official php:7.0-fpm image (which uses [`CMD ["php-fpm"]`](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/7.0/fpm/Dockerfile#L138)). In the entrypoint script, I expect the `$@` variable to contain the string `php-fpm` but it's empty.

```
marc@imac-marc:/opt/php-docker$ cat Dockerfile-php
FROM php:7.0-fpm
COPY utils/entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]

marc@imac-marc:/opt/php-docker$ cat utils/entrypoint.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "CMD = $@"

marc@imac-marc:/opt/php-docker$ docker build -t me:myImage -f Dockerfile-php .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   276 kB
Step 1 : FROM php:7.0-fpm
 ---> d66add11c05d
Step 2 : COPY utils/entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
 ---> a62ef60a202b
Removing intermediate container 20bd7782844e
Step 3 : RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
 ---> Running in 27af4ffbd6c0
 ---> 77fba35c804d
Removing intermediate container 27af4ffbd6c0
Step 4 : ENTRYPOINT /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
 ---> Running in 6779b16542ec
 ---> 326970218669
Removing intermediate container 6779b16542ec
Successfully built 326970218669

marc@imac-marc:/opt/php-docker$ docker run me:myImage
CMD =
```

If I add `CMD ["php-fpm"]` to my Dockerfile, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/5147 - it explains when and why this behaviour was implemented.